# Numpy, how to reshape a vector to multi column array

Tags: python, numpy

I am wondering how to use np.reshape to reshape a long vector into n columns array without giving the row numbers.

Normally I can find out the row number by `len(a)//n`:

```
a = np.arange(0, 10)
n = 2
b = a.reshape(len(a)//n,n)
```

If there a more direct way without using `len(a)//n`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use -1 on one dimension, numpy will figure out what this number should be:

```
a = np.arange(0, 10)
n = 2
b = a.reshape(-1, n)
```

The doc is pretty clear about this feature: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

> One shape dimension can be -1. In this case, the value is inferred
>   from the length of the array and remaining dimensions.